# MATLAB 2018b - Datafeed Toolbox: Retrieving tick data for a specific time range from Bloomberg

Tags: matlab, bloomberg, blpapi, datafeed

I am trying to retrieve tick data for a specific ticker for a specific time range from Bloomberg using MATLAB 2018b and its Datafeed Toolbox. In the documentation for the 'timeseries' function in the Datafeed Toolbox I found an example which does exactly what I need:

https://nl.mathworks.com/help/datafeed/blp.timeseries.html#mw_8b6c8864-9224-4345-973a-086c90603948

However, when running the sample code, also by opening the example itself in MATLAB using the command

```
openExample('datafeed/RetrieveTimeSeriesTickDataForDateTimeRangeWithFieldExample')
```

I get the following error:

```
Error using blp/timeseries (line 463)
Java exception occurred:
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
    at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
Error in deleteme (line 9)
d = timeseries(c,s,{startdate:enddate,starttime,endtime},interval,field);
```

Is anyone familiar with this error and a possible fix? Or is there a workaround available?

Thanks in advance for your response(s)!